# RStudio Shiny renderDataTable font size

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to reduce the font size in my renderDataTable but I cannot find any example that controls font size.  I have read that it is possible to control it through jquery but I cannot find any examples.  Any guidance would be very helpful as I am using Shiny ioslides presentation and the font size in my data tables is simply too large.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can put `dataTableOutput("tableName")` inside of `div()`and change the font using the `style` parameter. `style` takes CSS arguments.

For example, if have this...

> dataTableOutput("tableName")

you can change it like this...

> div(dataTableOutput("tableName"), style = "font-size:80%")

to make the font size 20% smaller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am building a Shiny presentation and the following UI code is the one that I have embedded in my Rmd file.  I don't have experience with <div> tags, so I was not able to implement your answer because I don't really know where and how to place the <div> tag. Do I also have to make a change in the css file?

Comment: In Shiny, you use the function ```div()``` as in my example. That will be converted to an HTML ```<div>``` tag when you're looking at the app in a browser, but you don't have to worry about that when you're programming Shiny. I'll modify my answer so it doesn't reference any concepts from HTML.

Comment: Thank YOu, I will wait for your modified answer

Comment: My attempt to implement your answer was to place the following line of code in my Rmd chunk just below the renderDatTable but it did not work. I believe you mentioned that I should place it within my UI code but I cannot figure out where and how.  div(dataTableOutput("economicExposure"), style = "font-size:50%")

Comment: Are you using a .Rmd file, or are you using ui.R/server.R?

Comment: Also, do you have a line that looks like this somewhere in your code? ```output$economicExposure <- renderDataTable({ your_data_frame })```

Comment: I am using an Rmd file and the shiny code is inside a code chunk. The mainPanel code looks like mainPanel( 
        tabsetPanel(id='RSQRM',
                    tabPanel("Portfolio", fluidRow(dataTableOutput(outputId="factorAttribution")),verbatimTextOutput(outputId='portfolioVolatility')),
                    tabPanel("Stock", plotOutput(outputId="expIndMkt")),
                    tabPanel("Economic", fluidRow(dataTableOutput(outputId="economicExposure")))
                  )
                ,width=9)
            )

Comment: output$economicExposure <- renderDataTable({
              
              sBetaObject <- paste('dtStockBeta',sModel(),sep="")
              datBeta <- get(sBetaObject)
              
              dat <- getStockBetas(oData=datBeta,sFactorOrStock=sFactorOrStock(),sSelection=input$selectFactorStock,sDate=input$selectDate,sLimitFactorGroup=c('Industry','Market','Currency'))
              
              dat
              
          },options = list(aLengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15),iDisplayLength = 5,bFilter = TRUE))

Comment: My shiny app renders without a problem, its just that the font size is very large and since this is a ioslide presentation, the fonts look disproportionately large in comparison to the slide size

Comment: Thank you so much, your edited answer worked like a charm.  It would be very helpful if the shiny documentation contained such examples as your solution was so easy to understand and implement.

Comment: tabPanel("Economic", fluidRow(div(dataTableOutput(outputId="economicExposure"),style = "font-size:80%")))

Comment: I wanted to do this myself and found the `div()` solution here. I tried it with my DataTables pages, but I noticed if one sorts by clicking on the column header on these resized tables, the triangle depicting the sorting is not rendered... Any ideas?

Comment: @20050 ... Could you please provide your files, maybe as a Github gist? (see http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson7/). Edit: On second thought, this probably deserves to be posted as its own question.

Comment: I checked again and the reason I wasn't seeing the arrows, or triangles, is because flash crashed, but after restarting the browser, everything went fine.

Comment: note this answer won't work if its wrapped around a `fillCol` or similar functions meant for use with `flex` in flexdashboards.  My guess is the tags interfere with the way `fillCol` gets the dimensions to fill the space.