# Possible incompatibilty "div" tags and updateSelectInput

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am working in a Shiny Flexdashboard and I having a issue with updateSelectInput, and CSS code... 
I would like alternatives to solve the issue...

I wanted to lower a table size but I am new in html, CSS and related stuff, so I found the inspiration from [here](http://alcantaraalcantara.blogspot.com/2013/03/r-rstudio-shiny-renderdatatable-font.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069224/rstudio-shiny-renderdatatable-font-size) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534677/reduce-font-size-of-datatable-in-a-flexdashboard) specifically mentioned as implemented in flexdashboard) and coded the similar to the following:

```
selectInput("Indicator","select",choices=c(),selected="NONE")
observe({

  Inds<-as.factor(mtcars[,2])%>%levels

  updateSelectInput(session,inputId="Indicator",choices=Inds)

})


  wellPanel(
    div (dataTableOutput ("OrigData"), style = "font-size: 80%"),
    dataTableOutput("OrigData"),
  )


output$OrigData<-DT::renderDataTable(mtcars)
```

It makes the lines smaller in the data table rendered as I want, but, the problem is, the selectInput "Indicator" is not updated.

What works: The selectInput "Indicator" is adequately updated if I comment/exclude the line

`div (dataTableOutput ("OrigData"), style = "font-size: 80%")`

So, I am unable to make they work simultaneously...

The same happens even if I put the select input on the sidebar and the data table in another tab...

There is a kind of incompatibility between the CSS's "div" code and updateSelectInput? What can I do to work with style in flexdashboard (specifically dataTableOutput font-size) without blocking the updateSelectInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a workaround, not exactly a solution. But I think it was a good idea to include how I worked around it...  It's related to [the answer indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655781/r-dt-datatable-font-size-change) and uses DT (as described [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/))
That's not exactly my initial intent, the rownames, title row remain with the original size, but a way to approach partially the issue.

````
    ```{r,echo=FALSE}

selectInput("Indicator","select",choices=c(),selected="NONE")
observe({

  Inds<-as.factor(mtcars[,2])%>%levels

  updateSelectInput(session,inputId="Indicator",choices=Inds)

})


  wellPanel(
    #div (dataTableOutput ("OrigData"), style = "font-size: 80%"),
    dataTableOutput("OrigData"),
  )


output$OrigData<-DT::renderDataTable(mtcars%>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  DT::formatStyle(columns = colnames(mtcars), fontSize = '50%')
  )

```
````